# Python Scoreboard

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to create a simple python scoreboard. Eventually, I will add buttons to increase and decrease the values. This my current code, How can I get it to print "New Game" and restart the loop 5 seconds after someone wins?

```
RedScore = 0
BlueScore = 0

while RedScore <= 5 and BlueScore <= 5:
    if RedScore == 5:
        print('RED WINS')
        break
    elif BlueScore == 5:
        print('BLUE WINS')
        break
    else:
        x = input("Who Scored? ")
        if x == 'Red':
            RedScore += 1
            print(RedScore)
        elif x == 'Blue':
            BlueScore += 1
            print(BlueScore)
        else:
            print('Bad Input')
```

Also, I want to add a condition that if you enter "REDRESET" the score for RED will = 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want it to wait 5 seconds just `sleep` for 5 seconds after the loop has run. Adding `REDRESET` is as simple as having another `elif`

```
from time import sleep
while RedScore <= 5 and BlueScore <= 5:
    if RedScore == 5:
        print('RED WINS')
        sleep(5)
        RedScore = BlueScore = 0 
    elif BlueScore == 5:
        print('BLUE WINS')
        sleep(5)
        BlueScore = RedScore = 0
    else:
        x = input("Who Scored? ")
        if x == 'Red':
            RedScore += 1
            print(RedScore)
        elif x == 'Blue':
            BlueScore += 1
            print(BlueScore)
        elif x == 'REDRESET':
            RedScore = 3
        else:
            print('Bad Input')
```